# Keeping the same margins with every device?

Tags: android, android-layout

So I have been experimenting today with different layouts and I finally got what I wanted, but when I was testing it on other devices with other screen dimensions it really turned out bad.

Is there anything what you can do to prevent this?

This is what I have:

[image]

And this is my XML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:background="@drawable/blurred_bj"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/logo_container"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button">
        <ImageView
                android:layout_marginBottom="85dp"
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/log"
                android:contentDescription="TODO"
                />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sign_in"
            android:id="@+id/sign_in"
            android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sign_up"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_above="@+id/sign_in"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/footer">
        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/news"
                android:id="@+id/news" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you I am using different margins, which I think is the cause of all the problems.

Comment: you must set the marigins programatically related to screen size of device.u can find screen size of device programaticaly

Comment: You have to assign margins (and paddings as well) in different res/values/dimens.xml files: see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)

Answer (score 1):

One month ago i'm stuck with the same problem. This paper were very helpful http://www.vanteon.com/downloads/Scaling_Android_Apps_White_Paper.pdf for me.

Hope this helps

Supporting different resources containing dimensions for `all` (really all?) available dimensions is a pain in ass. It's will be just a waste of time.

Use approach described in document.

Comment: Thank you, I have added their snippet into my application. But they using one named contents and the other is the container. But as you see I have one container which is the RelativeLayout and then I have 3 LinearLayouts. So how should I use it? Call the method 3 times?

Comment: Wrap your `RelativeLayout` into `FrameLayout` assign Id's and put them into scaling method. Assuming FrameLayout is a root call `scaleContents(findViewById(R.id.frame), findViewById(R.id.relative))`. As a hint - forget about `wrap_content` and `match_parent` and specify all in fixed sizes. Scaling method will take care about this.

Comment: If u still experiences any troubles with this i can send you sample application.

Comment: Hm, I can't get it to fit my design. I'd appreciate if you could send me the sample application.

Comment: Sizes becomes available after onCreate. Just note the use of `ViewTreeObserver`: 
http://www.filedropper.com/scaleapp

Also take in account that it will scale uniformely so if you launch this on tablet it will be scaled appropriately (left and right edges will be empty).

Comment: Alright, I see it now. Would it be possible to create an UI with FrameLayout and RelativeLayout for my issue?

Comment: I think yes. Why not? Wrap RelativeLayout and set fixed width/height. Wrap it with FrameLayout and set `match_parent`/`match_parent`. Look at document.

Comment: Because I just spent an hour on trying to create it, and I couldn't do it, unfortunately..